# restlet post getFirstValue always returns null

Tags: java, rest, jax-rs, restlet

I am using postman client to send RES request to this restless router:

```
public Representation createAgent(Representation entity) {
    Form form = new Form(entity);

    String user = form.getFirstValue("user");
    String password = form.getFirstValue("password");


    System.out.println("user: "+ user);
    System.out.println("password: "+ password);
    System.out.println("form: "+ form.toString());

    return (agent.save(getUser(),getPassword()))
            ? new StringRepresentation("user "+ user +" created", MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
            : new StringRepresentation("agent creation failed",MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN);

}
```

Usera and password are always null although printing form.toString() shows:

```
[[------WebKitFormBoundaryb4FkGv8CgddIf8rn
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="user"

ali
------WebKitFormBoundaryb4FkGv8CgddIf8rn
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="password"

dsndfjo32
------WebKitFormBoundaryb4FkGv8CgddIf8rn--
]]
```

Below is the full postman request in preview mode:

```
POST /v1/agents HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:9000
Authorization: Basic c2NvdHQ6amRmZ2pkZnRnaA==
Cache-Control: no-cache
 Postman-Token: ef58fda2-8974-0d9f-7a23-10c94df8552e
 Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=----                        WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW

 ----WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW
  Content-Disposition: form-data; name="user"

 ali
 ----WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW
  Content-Disposition: form-data; name="password"

  dsndfjo32
 ----WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In fact, if you look at the content type of the data you send within your request, this corresponds to a multipart content and not a URL-encoded form.

The code you use within your server resource only applies to URL-encoded form (content-type `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`). So it's normal that you can get nothing. For information, the payload of such approach would be something like that:

```
user=my+user&password=my+password
```

Perhaps it's something you want. If so choose the tab `x-www-form-urlencoded` within Postman...

Multipart is generally used when you want to upload a file with additional data. If multipart is what you want, you should have a look at this link: http://restlet.com/technical-resources/restlet-framework/guide/2.3/extensions/fileupload.

Hope it will help you,
Thierry